# Format date with timezone in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, timezone

Using angularjs 1.2.26 i cant format my date input to the desired timezone, here's an example: http://plnkr.co/edit/CxCqoR3Awcl1NFrCZYjx?p=preview

```
{{'2015-07-10T12:37:08Z' | date : "MMMM d, y 'at' h:mma Z" : 'America/Bahia'}}
```

and

```
{{'2015-07-10T12:37:08Z' | date : "MMMM d, y 'at' h:mma Z" : 'Europe/Paris'}}
```

gave the same output respecting my browser's local timezone and ignoring the timezone i've set.

Answer (score 4):

There are two problems:

- The time zone support looks like it was introduced post-1.2.26
- The time zone support doesn't take an arbitrary TZDB ID. From the docs for [v1.4.1](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.1/docs/api/ng/filter/date):

  > Timezone to be used for formatting. It understands UTC/GMT and the continental US time zone abbreviations, but for general use, use a time zone offset, for example, '+0430' (4 hours, 30 minutes east of the Greenwich meridian) If not specified, the timezone of the browser will be used.

  In [v1.3.16](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.16/docs/api/ng/filter/date) it's even more restricted:

  > Timezone to be used for formatting. Right now, only 'UTC' is supported. If not specified, the timezone of the browser will be used.

So if you change your example to use:

```
<script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.2/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.2"></script>
```

and then:

```
<span>{{'2015-07-10T12:37:08' | date : "MMMM d, y 'at' h:mma Z" : 'PST'}}</span>
<br/>
<span>{{'2015-07-10T12:37:08' | date : "MMMM d, y 'at' h:mma Z" : 'EDT'}}</span>
```

(for example) then you'll get output of:

```
July 10, 2015 at 3:37AM -0800 
July 10, 2015 at 7:37AM -0400
```

Comment: Thank's Jon, i know the 1.2.26 got no timezone filter feature, maybe i wasnt clear enough for that but i need a way to format the date with a defined timezone.

Comment: @Fourat: well it doesn't look like angularjs is likely to support that any time soon. Maybe you should look at moment.js?

Comment: @Jon Skeet : You also know AngularJs and help us. its amazing.

Comment: @GulMdErshad: No, I don't know AngularJS at all. I was just reading documentation...

Comment: @Jon Skeet: You have helped us so much specially in C#. 
You are my ideal in Software Development. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

Check https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.26/docs/api/ng/filter/date

You won't find anything related to time zone in filter.